# Azure App Service Plan Hardware Failures

Tags: azure

I am new to the Azure platform and hosting in general and I am currently moving some web apps to Azure Paas and have configured a single App Service Plan which contains 3 applications.

I have read all the documentation I can find and I know the plan guarantees 99.95% up time but I cant find any info in regard to hardware failures. i.e. if there is a hardware failure on a rack where my app is hosted am I automatically covered by the plan? Does my app exist in multiple fault domains?

Hope someone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see the details here. I'd say hardware failures are considered as downtime:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/app-service/v1_4/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft guarantee that Apps running in a customer subscription will be available 99.95% of the time.

**Note:** No SLA is provided for Apps under either the **Free** or **Shared** tiers.

For more information, refer [SLA for App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/legal/sla/app-service/v1_4/).

This SLA works based on the fault domain and update domains, understand [how fault domains and update domains works in Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/plankytronixx/2015/05/01/azure-exam-prep-fault-domains-and-update-domains/).